# Angular - Argument of type null is not assignable to parameter of type IUser

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular13

In my Angular-13 project I have this model interface:

```js
export interface IUser {
   email: string;
   token: string;
}
```

And also this service:

```js
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  loadCurrentUser(token: string) {
    if (token === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', `bearer ${token}`);

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'account', {headers}).pipe(
      map((user: IUser) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

However, I got this error:

> argument of type null is not assignable to parameter of type IUser

and `null` is highlighted in:

```js
this.currentUserSource.next(null);
```

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReplaySubject`.next()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject#next) is expected to receive parameter with `T` value.

> next(value: T): void
>
> Parameters
>
> > value    Type: T.
>
> Returns
> void

which `T` is `IUser` based on below statement:

```js
private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
```

---

### Solution

You can resolve it by declaring `currentUserSource` as `ReplaySubject<IUser | null>` type.

```js
private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser | null>(1);
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ni7ybq?file=src/app/account.service.ts)